# Combine two queries - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am working on an sql query where I need the results from two queries. The first query is this:

```
select s.code, count(s.code), s.name from course_staff c join courses e on 
c.course = e.id 
join subjects s on e.subject = s.id 
join semesters x on e.semester = x.id 
where c.staff = 5033690
group by s.code, s.name
having count(s.code) > 8;
```

This results in the following:

```
    code   | count |              name
 ----------+-------+--------------------------------
  MATS1464 |    10 | Professional Comm&Presentation
  MATS6605 |     9 | Prof Comm & Presentation
```

The second query:

```
select count(distinct s.code) from course_staff c join courses e 
on c.course = e.id
join subjects s on e.subject = s.id
join semesters x on e.semester = x.id
where c.staff = 5033690
having count(s.code)>20;
```

This results in the following:

```
 count
-------
    30
```

I need to combine both the having count conditions from the above two queries into one query so that I can use it in a function or view. Please advise on how can I join these two queries so that both the having conditions are met. Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Huh?  Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're asking for here.  One query has a having clause with count(s.code)>20 and the other has count(s.code)>8 ... those are the same field so I'm not sure how you think you could combine the queries. Do you need the columns from the first query to show up in the second one?  Or something else?

Comment: Well the first query is basically the number of times a particular subject has been taught over the years and the second query is the TOTAL number of distinct subjects taught over the years.

Comment: So you want this two results on the same row, don't you? You want a count and a total_count?

Comment: Thats right! I want that exactly @d34n5

Comment: `having count(s.code)>20`?..  why?..

Comment: Please add at least the definition of your tables (use in psql: \d yourtablefoo).

Comment: Also, which version of Postgres are you using? SELECT version(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea (using Postgres' Window Functions):

```
WITH  
  code_name (code, name) AS (  
    SELECT s.code, s.name  
    FROM course_staff c  
    JOIN courses e ON c.course = e.id  
    JOIN subjects s ON e.subject = s.id  
    JOIN semesters x ON e.semester = x.id  
    WHERE c.staff = 5033690  
),  
  code_name_counts (code, name, count_both, count_total) AS (  
    SELECT DISTINCT code,
                    name,
                    COUNT(code) OVER (PARTITION BY code, name),                                     
                    COUNT(code) OVER (PARTITION BY code)                                                  
    FROM code_name
)  
SELECT code, name, count_both, count_total  
FROM code_name_counts  
WHERE count_both > 8 AND count_total > 20 ;
```

Consider it a shot in the dark without further knowledge about your requirements.

And for testing purposes (without the WHERE):

```
WITH  
  code_name (code, name) AS (  
    VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')  
),  
  code_name_counts (code, name, count_both, count_total) AS (  
    SELECT DISTINCT code,  
           name,  
           COUNT(code) OVER (PARTITION BY code, name),   
           COUNT(code) OVER (PARTITION BY code)  
    FROM code_name  
)  
SELECT code, name, count_both, count_total  
FROM code_name_counts ;
```

which gives

```
 code | name | count_both | count_total 
------+------+------------+-------------
    1 | a    |          1 |           2
    2 | b    |          2 |           2
    1 | b    |          1 |           2
    3 | c    |          1 |           1
```

And here is an example without `DISTINCT` and `PARTITION BY`:

```
WITH  
  code_name (code, name) AS (  
    VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')  
),  
  code_name_distinct (code, name) AS (  
    SELECT DISTINCT code, name  
    FROM code_name  
),  
  code_name_counts (code, name, count_both, count_total) AS (  
    SELECT code,  
           name,   
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM code_name a  
            WHERE a.code = x.code AND a.name = x.name),  
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM code_name b  
            WHERE b.code = x.code)  
    FROM code_name_distinct x  
)  
SELECT code, name, count_both, count_total  
FROM code_name_counts
```

which returns the same result as above.